# Creating standard error bars in lattice xyplot graphs with multiple panels

Tags: lattice, errorbar

I have a dataset in which I am graphing means from 4 treatments over time, along with their standard errors, at 2 sites. The standard error bars are not being assigned properly to their respective means --they are going to both panels - can you please advise? See example:

```
d <- data.frame(site=rep(1:2,each=12),time=rep(1:3,8),trt=rep(rep(1:4,each=3),2)) 
d$mn <- rnorm(24,4,1)
d$se <- rnorm(24,2,1)
d$ul <- d$mn+d$se  # create y value for standard error upper limit

my.panel <- function(x,y, ...){
    panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
    panel.arrows(x, y, x, d$ul, length = 0.1,
      angle = 90)
      }

xyplot(mn ~ time|site,data=d,
    group = trt,
    type=c('p','l'),
    panel = my.panel
)
```